# Android application crashes if backgrounded while holding navigation drawer item

Tags: android, crash, navigation-drawer

I have an application that uses the navigation drawer design pattern as per the Android Developer website implementation. Basically each item in the list opens a fragment (as per the normal paradigm). I have found that if I hold down one of the navigation drawer items while the application is backgrounded (which can be done by hitting the home key or when a phone call comes in) the application crashes.

Notably, the crash occurs when I remove my finger from the screen and so you can hold your finger on the screen indefinitely and it won't crash until the finger is lifted.

Stacktrace is as follows,... so it seems I might be able to answer my own question in a moment - thanks for the (sort-of-obvious-now) prompt :-)

```
07-29 09:11:03.182    5044-5044/au.com.xxx.yyy E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATALEXCEPTION: main
Process: au.com.xxx.yyy, PID: 5044
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1323)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1341)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:597)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:575)
        at au.com.xxx.yyy.userInterface.MainActivity.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(MainActivity.java:264)
        at au.com.xxx.yyy.userInterface.NavigationDrawerFragment.selectItem(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:235)
        at au.com.xxx.yyy.userInterface.NavigationDrawerFragment$1.onItemClick(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:104)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:308)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1478)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3480)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4838)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:4601)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8017)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2129)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2411)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2144)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2411)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2144)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2411)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2144)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2411)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2144)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2280)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1615)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2544)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2228)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8212)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4499)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4367)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3925)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3979)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3948)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4059)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3956)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4116)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3925)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3979)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3948)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3956)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3925)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6306)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6210)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6181)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6146)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6386)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
```

Comment: Do you have the stack trace from logcat ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any who follow the answer is quite simple (and implied by the stack trace - thanks Ashwin).

In the standard pattern for showing a fragment and making the back button work looks like:

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position, boolean fromSavedInstanceState) {
    ....
    ....
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
    // and add the transaction to the back stack
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    // add transaction to back stack so it can be reversed
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    // Commit the transaction
    transaction.commit();
}
```

If you have already performed the onSaveInstanceState(...) call then the transaction.commit() line throws the exception shown above.

Hence I created a flag to say whether I was currently processing an onSaveInstanceState call which I clear in onCreate and onResume. I then use this flag to by-pass all the BackStack stuff in onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(...)

Voila! Obvious once you get your head in the right spot!!